# How to combine two arrays to one by their indices in the result?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Suppose that I have two arrays:

```
In [41]: x = np.array([1, 4, 9])
In [42]: y = np.array([3, 5, 7, 11])
```

And their indices in the result array:

```
In [43]: ix = [1, 3, 4]
In [44]: iy = [0, 2, 5, 6]
```

The result array should be `r = array([ 3,  1,  5,  4,  9,  7, 11])` which satisfied `all(r[ix] == x)` and `all(r[iy] = y)`. I already known the verbose  solution, and I want to find a better one (may a one line solution using something like `np.where` or `np.select`).

```
In [45]: r = np.empty(shape=len(x)+len(y))
In [46]: r[ix] = x; r[iy] = y; r
Out[46]: array([ 3.,  1.,  5.,  4.,  9.,  7., 11.])
```

Comment: I think your way is already the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.array([x[1] for x in sorted(zip(ix, x) + zip(iy, y)))]`

But I don't know if it is optimal or maybe numpy have further optimizations.